# Controlling a toggle of a `while bool` loop with asyncIO

Tags: python, python-asyncio, mido

I am trying to create a sequencer using the `mido` library.
For the sequencer, I want to be able to toggle it on and off using a button. How can I achieve this, using `asyncIO` for the sequencer?

I tried writing a function within the `Sequencer` class that toggles its state, then calling it from my `main` function:

`sequencer.py`:

```py
async def runSequencer(self) -> None:
    while self.isRunning:
        #Sequencer code here

async def toggleSequencer(self) -> None:
    print(self.voice, "TOGGLE")
    if self.isRunning:
        await self.pauseSequencer()
    else:
        await self.runSequencer()
    await asyncio.sleep(0.001)
```

`__main__.py`:

```py
async def readInport() -> None:
    for msg in inport.iter_pending():
        if (msg.type != 'sysex'):
            type, ch, note, vel = functions.unpack_message(msg)
            print(type, ch, note, vel) # print() mentioned below
            queue = []
            if type == "control_change" and note == 19 and vel == 127: # Wanted button pressed
                time.sleep(0.001)
                queue = [seq.toggleSequencer() for seq in sequencers]
        else:
            print("other")

        await asyncio.gather(*queue)

async def main():
    while True:
        await asyncio.gather(readInport())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

This runs the sequencers as intended when I first press the button, but the marked print() doesn't run when I press it again.

However, the notes stop playing for a microsecond when I press the button. This doesn't happen when I press any other button. (Edit: after checking now, it does seem to happen whenever I press any button.)

---

This is my first time working with asyncIO, and one of my first projects in python, so excuse my ignorance and the sloppiness that may be present in my code.